# Is the profiler wrong, or is the scheduling messed up, or both?

Tags: cuda, cuda-streams

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <unistd.h>

using clock_value_t = long long;

__device__ void gpu_sleep(clock_value_t sleep_cycles)
{
    clock_value_t start = clock64();
    clock_value_t cycles_elapsed;
    do { cycles_elapsed = clock64() - start; }
    while (cycles_elapsed < sleep_cycles);
}

__global__ void dummy(clock_value_t duration_in_cycles)
{
    gpu_sleep(duration_in_cycles);
}

int main()
{
    const clock_value_t duration_in_clocks = 1e7;
    const size_t buffer_size = 2e7;
    constexpr const auto num_streams = 8;

    std::array<char*, num_streams> host_ptrs;
    std::array<char*, num_streams> device_ptrs;
    std::array<cudaStream_t, num_streams> streams;
    for (auto i=0; i<num_streams; i++) {
        cudaMallocHost(&host_ptrs[i], buffer_size);
        cudaMalloc(&device_ptrs[i], buffer_size);
        cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&streams[i], cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    for (auto i=0; i<num_streams; i++) {
        cudaMemcpyAsync(device_ptrs[i], host_ptrs[i], buffer_size, cudaMemcpyDefault, streams[i]);
        dummy<<<128, 128, 0, streams[i]>>>(duration_in_clocks);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(host_ptrs[i], device_ptrs[i], buffer_size, cudaMemcpyDefault, streams[i]);
    }
    usleep(50000);
    for (auto i=0; i<num_streams; i++) { cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[i]); }
    for (auto i=0; i<num_streams; i++) {
        cudaFreeHost(host_ptrs[i]);
        cudaFree(device_ptrs[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm running it on an GTX Titan X, with CUDA 8.0.61, on Fedora 25, with driver 375.66. The timeline I'm seeing is this:

[image]

There a few things wrong with this picture:

- As far as I can recall there can only be one HtoD transfer at a time.
- All of the memory transfers should take basically the same amount of time - they're of the same amount of data; and there's nothing else interesting going on with the PCIe bus to affect transfer rates so much.
- Some DtoH bars like like they're stretched out until something happens on another stream.
- There's this huge gap in which there seems to be no Computer and no real I/O. And even if the DtoH for all previously-completed kernels was to occupy that gap, that would still leave a very significant amount of time. That actually looks like a scheduling issue rather than a profiling error.

So, how should I interpret this timeline? And where does the problem lie? (Hopefully not with the programmer...)

I should mention that with less streams (e.g. 2) the timeline looks very nice on the same SW+HW:

[image]